# open differents threads using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms

i build an application how take Pcap file (wireshark file) and play the packets, the play operation is with exe file who get file path and interface int.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    shouldContinue = true;
    btnStart.Enabled = false;
    btnStop.Enabled = true;
    groupBoxAdapter.Enabled = false;
    groupBoxRootDirectory.Enabled = false;
    string filePath = string.Empty;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lvFiles.Items.Count && shouldContinue; i++)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { filePath = lvFiles.Items[i].Tag.ToString(); });
            pcapFile = new PcapFile();
            pcapFile.sendQueue(filePath, adapter);
        }

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
            groupBoxAdapter.Enabled = true;
            groupBoxRootDirectory.Enabled = true;
        });
    });
}
```

the sendQueue code:

```
public void sendQueue(string filePath, int deviceNumber)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\Downloads\SendQueue\sendQueue.exe");
            processStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {2}{1}{2}", (deviceNumber).ToString(), filePath, "\"");
            processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

            using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
            {
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you need these to run serially, why run them in background threads at all? If you need your UI to be responsive, why not run a loop inside the background thread?

Comment: can i have an example how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doen't look that you need Background worker.

```
     List<string> tags = new List<string>();
     foreach (object item in lvFiles.Items)
     {
        tags.Add(item.tag.ToString());
     }

     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < tags.Count && shouldContinue; i++)
       {
           sendQueue(tags[i], adapter);
       }

        //...
     }
```

Comment: @user1269592 this is impossible, write how you used it

Comment: @user1269592 take all invokes away and just call sendQueue directly inside of for loop

Comment: if i am just call sendQueue without the this.Invoke... cross threading error received

Comment: @user1269592 I guess you see it only for buttons and only in debugger, right? The first can be removed safely

Comment: the cross threading i see if i removed  pcapFile.sendQueue from the this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { ... } but still the GUI freeze

Comment: @user1269592 wait, what is lvFiles, listview? Then it's understandable. Don't pass it to the thread, but save it's count in int variable and pass it than

Comment: yes, lvFiles it's my listview but how can i save it ? out of the for loop i cannot declare lvFiles.Items[i]

Comment: @user1269592 save it as list of strings for example

Comment: see my update, now it's working well but this is a correct way to do it ?

Comment: @user1269592 You can avoid invocation overhead. You can also declare sendQueue as static. See my edit

Comment: what are the advantages of declare sendQueue as static ?

Comment: @user1269592 you don't need to instantiate the class, which means you can call the function directly

Answer (score 1):

Your UI thread is most likely blocked because the pcapFile.sendQueue is synchronous. This means even though your async loop queues the play files the UI thread is busy 99.99% of the time playing the file's content. This may or may not be the case since you haven't posted PcapFile's source.

The task to make your UI responsive is a bit more involving, you need to restructure PcapFile to load up a frame (audio? video?) at a time and let the UI thread run the rest of the time or even to work completely in the background.

The form design should also rely on events from PcapFile instead of trying to run it in a BackgroundWorker

Comment: see my update, now it's working well but this is a correct way to do it ?

Comment: Instead of WaitForExit you can hook to the event Exited on Process. You will have to make sure you unhook from the event right after you receive it to prevent memory leaks